# How to get a correct event target in Backbone.js View that is listen to an event of jqGrid?

Tags: backbone.js, jqgrid, backbone-views, backbone-events

I use `jqGrid` together with `Backbone.js` and I have the view that represents the grid. The code is below:

```
var GridView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize:     function(){
        _.bindAll(this);
    },
    beforeSelectRow:function(e){
        return $(e.target).is('img') ? false : true;
    },
    render:         function(){
        var self = this;

        this.$el.load(
            this.collection.url + 'grid/',
            function(){
                self.$jqGrid = self.$('.jqGrid');
                self.$jqGrid.on('jqGridBeforeSelectRow',self.beforeSelectRow);
            }
        );

        return this;
    }
});
```

The grid's row can contain an image. If I click on some image, I will expect that the grid's row would not be selected. I listen the triggered event `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` which is triggered by `jqGrid` but I get an incorrect event target. I expect that the event target is an image. I found the similar question [JQGrid Not select row when clicking in a particular cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5967754) and there is all works. What is wrong with my listener?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't use Backbone myself, but I hope that I understand you correct. You want to deny selection of rows of the grid if the click was on the image which is inside of the grid. The callback `beforeSelectRow` is the event handler of `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` event. If I understand you correct then the same event handler one could bind the the following way

```
$("#list").bind("jqGridBeforeSelectRow", function (e) {
    return $(e.target).is('img') ? false : true;
});
```

The event handler is wrong because `e.target` is always DOM of `<table>` element which is base element of the grid. The reason is that `jqGridBeforeSelectRow` is custom *event of the `<table>` element*.

Correct implementation would be

```
$("#list").bind("jqGridBeforeSelectRow", function (e, rowid, eventOriginal) {
    return !$(eventOriginal.target).is("img");
});
```

The `eventOriginal` represent event object of the original `click` event which initiated the "jqGridBeforeSelectRow" event. I think that transformation of the changes to Backbone version will be clear for you.

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TestChart1.htm) demonstrate the result.

Answer (score 2):

First thing, please change:

```
return $(e.target).is('img') ? false : true;
```

To:

```
return !$(e.target).is('img');
```

Secondly, you should have a look at [jqGrid's doc](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) which says that the arguments the listener takes are (rowid, e). So basically the *e* argument you use is instead the rowid, with no target key whatsoever.

Thirdly, have also a look at [Backbone's doc](http://backbonejs.org/#Events-listenTo) and if your version is recent enough (or if you can update), consider removing `_.bindAll(this)` and instead use the Model#listenTo method like `self.listenTo(self.$jqGrid, self.beforeSelectRow)`.

Last but not least, are you sure the beforeSelectRow event is triggered by your $jqGrid element? It could be otherwise. But that's just something to verify if it doesn't work after those changes.

Comment: +1 from me. I think that you cached correctly the main problems. I described in my answer how the problem and the solution could be formulated in term of jQuery and jqGrid.